# .NET and Outlook COM

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Does outlook (2003 or 2007) provides an event for new mails received so I can just add an event handler in my c# app?

Also, i have read issues about a dialog box that appears when other apps access outlook. When does this actually happens? and how is this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the [NewMailEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171304(v=office.11).aspx) event is supported in Outlook 2003 and up. It is preferred over the NewMail event because it includes the ID's of the new messages so you don't have to figure out what is new.

[The dialog box](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) occurs when you attempt to access certain protected properties of Outlook objects such as the sender of a message. This is (a pretty weak) effort to prevent email address harvesting.

Outlook 2007 and 2010 won't show this dialog if you have up-to-date virus software.